# Flutter Getx: Can obs create a global variable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

How to make obs a global variable?

Have an option of Getx that can create a global variable?

For the example:

```
class Test extends GetxController {
  RxString a = "".obs;
}
```

Page 1:

```
Test test =  Get.put(Test());
print(test.a.value); //""
test.a.value = "55555";
print(test.a.value); //"55555"
```

Page 2:

```
Test test =  Get.put(Test());
print(test.a.value); //""
```

Comment: use **GetxService** and put **main()** and use **Get.find<Service>()** any place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Now, I am using

> Class + static

Class:

```
Class Global {
     static Rx<String> name = "me".obs;
     static ProfileObject profile = ProfileObject();
}
```

Use:

```
Obx(()=>Text(Global.name.value)),
Obx(()=>Text(Global.profile.age.value)),
```

It is easy to use, don't setting just use static in class.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your class into main with `Get.put(Test());` and it would be something like:

```
void main() {
  Get.put(Test());
  runApp(...);
}
```

In your test class add the following code: `static Test get to => Get.find<Test>();`

Your `Test` class would look like this:

```
class Test extends GetxController {
 static Test get to => Get.find<Test>();
  RxString a = "".obs;
}
```

Now you have your global class and to send it to call it would be as follows:

```
Test.to.a
```

You would use it in the following way:

```
//IMPORT TEST CLASS
//get the same instance that has already been created
Test test =  Test.to.a; 
print(test.value);
```

Comment: I am trying to solve a somewhat similar problem, which is to pass a value from within main () to a class which lets me write to a local variable and then route to the appropriate page.  Where do I create the actual value of test.value within main?

Comment: How are you setting the value of test.value and what is Test.to.a?

Answer (score 0):

`Get.put()` creates single instances, however, if you want to create a global controller, there's `Get.find()` which fetches the last instance of the controller created and shares it, that way global access can be achieved.

You can read more about this [here](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/dependency-management/instantiated-method-class)

Note, to use `Get.find()`, an instance needs to be created earlier.

Your new code will look like this:

```
class Test extends GetxController {
  RxString a = "".obs;
}
```

Page 1:

```
Test test =  Get.put(Test());
print(test.a.value); //""
test.a("55555");
print(test.a.value); //"55555"
```

Page 2:

```
Test test =  Get.find<Test>();
print(test.a.value); //"55555"
```

Comment: Thank you. It works!
Sometimes I need to use the latest values.
But it isn't truly a global instance.
Now, I am using Test testGlobals =  Get.put(Test); in the same class file.
But I still think my method might not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your work needs the latest value you can follow the comment of @Sagnik Biswas. It works!

Now, I am using basic globals instances.

test_cont.dart:

```
TestCont testContGlobals =  Get.put(TestCont());
class TestCont extends GetxController {
  RxString a = "".obs;
}
```

But I still think my method might not be correct.

Are there any disadvantages to this method?